# How to render results from a component as cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, bootstrap-4

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJEfw.png)
struggling to return json data from https://blockchain.info/blocks?format=json to show the time, hash and height data as cards

i've tried showing the Json data fetched from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users and it worked and everything displayed as cards

from list.js

```
import React from 'react'

    const List = ({ list }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <center><h1>Blockchain List</h1></center>
          {list.map((list) => (
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{list.blocks.hash}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{list.blocks.time}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">{list.blocks.height}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    };

    export default List;

from App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from './components/list';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    list: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://blockchain.info/blocks?format=json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ list: data})
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <List list={this.state.list} />
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I expected the Json data to be returned as cards but the only thing returned was the Blockchain  element

Comment: upload screen shot what you are getting right now

Comment: @Kinjal done, the link is at the beginning

Comment: this.setState({ list: data.blocks}) try to set

Comment: @AhmedRebai just tried, still the same output on the <h1>

Comment: Your problem is in the API call , the api server is not returning teh results correctly

Answer (score 1):

You need to inspect what data is before assuming it is iterable. If you go to https://blockchain.info/blocks?format=json and open up dev tools and paste the following into console:

```
fetch('https://blockchain.info/blocks?format=json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.warn(data)
    })
    .catch(console.log)
```

It will actually show `data` has a key of `blocks` which points to the list of elements you want to iterate over. So you should be setting state to: `this.setState({ list: data.blocks })`

You will then need to update the body of your list component to reflect the shape of data you're iterating over from:

```
<div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{list.blocks.hash}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{list.blocks.time}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">{list.blocks.height}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

to

```
<div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{list.hash}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{list.time}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">{list.height}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks i just tried doing that and still no changes. i also restarted the server to make sure but still nothing

Comment: Do you have any errors in console from the fetch request?

Comment: I've applied to the changes suggested into a codesandbox you can view here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-feather-ri0gm?fontsize=14 - The fetch request always failed due to a CORS issue so I pasted in the network response from a successful request and it worked fine so it might your fetch requested isn't resolving and then the error is being caught and it's never calling set state.

Answer (score 1):

While you' re displaying just change the name of List.map(list) to List.map(elem)

```
import React from 'react'

        const List = ({ list }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <center><h1>Blockchain List</h1></center>
              {list.map((elem) => (
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{elem.hash}</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{elem.time}</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">{elem.height}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          )
        };

    export default List;
```

I just added &cors=true to the fetch api call

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    list: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://blockchain.info/blocks?format=json&cors=true')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ list: data.blocks})
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <List list={this.state.list} />
    )
  }
}
```

It's working , check this https://codesandbox.io/s/still-fog-wyj5f?fontsize=14

Comment: I did but this is what it says = Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.